# React Navigation not working in a conditional statement

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

React navigation not working in my react native app when using it inside a conditional statement, it kept returning the error

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name": "screenname"}
> was not handled by any navigator.
> Do you have a screen named 'screenname'?

It only works if I minimize the screen and I return back,

Here is the code that handles the login process

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native"

const navigation = useNavigation()
const onLogin = async (data: FormData) => {
authenticationStore.login(data.email, data.password).then(() => {
  if (authenticationStore.isAuthenticated) {
    navigation.navigate('app', {
      screen: 'home',
    })
  }else if(authenticationStore.response == 'timeout'){
    alert('Request timed out')
  }else{
    alert('Invalid email or password')
  }
}
).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
}
)}
```

And Here is my Navigator

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native"
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme, DarkTheme, NavigatorScreenParams } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack"
import { navigationRef, useBackButtonHandler } from "./navigation-utilities"
import { SplashNavigator, SplashNavigatorParamList } from "./splash/splash-navigator"
import { AuthNavigator, AuthNavigatorParamList } from "./auth/auth-navigator"
import { BottomNavigator, BottomNavigatorParamList } from "./bottom/bottom-navigator"
import { useStores } from "../models"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"

export type NavigatorParamList = {
  splash: NavigatorScreenParams<SplashNavigatorParamList>
  auth: NavigatorScreenParams<AuthNavigatorParamList>
  app: NavigatorScreenParams<BottomNavigatorParamList>
 }

// Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<NavigatorParamList>()

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      initialRouteName="app"
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="app" component={BottomNavigator} />
      {/**  Your screens go here */}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const AuthStack = () => {
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}
    initialRouteName="splash"
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="splash" component={SplashNavigator} />
    <Stack.Screen name="auth" component={AuthNavigator} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

interface NavigationProps extends Partial<React.ComponentProps<typeof NavigationContainer>> { }

export const AppNavigator = (props: NavigationProps) => {
  const {authenticationStore} = useStores()
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme()
  useBackButtonHandler(canExit)
   return (
  
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      theme={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
      {...props}
    >
      {authenticationStore.isAuthenticated ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

AppNavigator.displayName = "AppNavigator"

const exitRoutes = ["welcome"]
export const canExit = (routeName: string) => exitRoutes.includes(routeName)
```

Every condition in the above code works except for the navigation that won't work except I minimize my screen and open back. I am actively using the following packages

```
   "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "~6.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "~6.0.1",
```

Note, i am using the infitered ignite react native boilerplate. and have tried using different navigation methods and still get the same thing.

Comment: Can you past the code where you are setting up the navigation with its screens?

Comment: @yousoumar i have update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got to learn that i didn't add the mob-x observer to my navigation stack which i did, and now the navigation is working accordingly